# Pytorch data.random_split() doesn't split randomly

Tags: pytorch, classification, python-3.8

I am trying to split my custom dataset randomly into test and train. The code runs and outputs the test and train folders successfully, but I need the test and train sets to be different each time I ran the code. Isn't this what randomly splitting supposed to mean/do?

p.s. just for clarification, the data is images, so I expect to see different images chosen for test and train sets each time I execute the code.

```
#Set the random seeds for reproducibility
SEED = 1234

random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

TRAIN_RATIO = 0.9

data_dir = 'Data Set 1'
images_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'images')
train_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'train')
test_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'test')

if os.path.exists(train_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(train_dir)
if os.path.exists(test_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(test_dir)

os.makedirs(train_dir)
os.makedirs(test_dir)

classes = os.listdir(images_dir)

for c in classes:

    class_dir = os.path.join(images_dir, c)

    images = os.listdir(class_dir)

    n_train = int(len(images) * TRAIN_RATIO)
    n_test = len(images) - n_train
    train_images, test_images = data.random_split(images,
                                               [n_train, n_test])

    os.makedirs(os.path.join(train_dir, c), exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(test_dir, c), exist_ok=True)

    for image in train_images:
        image_src = os.path.join(class_dir, image)
        image_dst = os.path.join(train_dir, c, image)
        shutil.copyfile(image_src, image_dst)

    for image in test_images:
        image_src = os.path.join(class_dir, image)
        image_dst = os.path.join(test_dir, c, image)
        shutil.copyfile(image_src, image_dst)
```

Comment: You are fixing the random seed, why do you then expect this to produce different results...?

Comment: I see, thank you!
 I thought that would be a different variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not random because you set the random seed. Think of the seed as a random number - if you define the seed, the number is not random anymore. If you don't define it, you will get a random seed every time.
Just comment out these lines :)

```
SEED = 1234

random.seed(SEED)
np.random.seed(SEED)
torch.manual_seed(SEED)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(SEED)
```

Alternatively, just do this: `SEED = random.randint(1, 1000)` to get a random number between 1 and 1000. This will let you print the value of `SEED`, if you need that for some reason.

You can see how the seed function works here:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_random_seed.asp

Comment: quick question, the size of the data set does not change/limit the SEED range? I mean, can I just leave it undefined and run experiments with different datasets?

Comment: The seed value is not related to the size of the data. The seed is just a number that specifies a fixed number that everything random "depends on", thus making it no longer truly random. This is useful if you want the random function to return the same random number each time. If you leave it undefined, you will most likely not get the same result next time you run it, since the seed is random by default.

Comment: Yep, I got it! ran it a couple of times with the fixed and random SEED